# Upgraded to 14.04, nothing works

Tags: 14.04, upgrade

I just upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04, had to reinstall (rescue) grub. 
http://paste.ubuntu.com/24273276

I can only get to login page and wallpaper, no file manager or applications will load, no desktop, only terminal will open, everything else makes me re-log in. One black page has a series of 2 digit number columns with "drm:drm_block_invalid" at the top. I probably should have accepted new configurations than save my old. Everything was going fine until the very end, d(?)config wouldn't acknowledge my pw so I had to abort. I can't get on-line with the 14.04 upgrade, am using my old 12.04 CD to type this.

Comment: I was able to get online with the guest session but with login! I cannot access any of my file storage, says I don't have permissions(!)

Comment: Where went all my apps? and bookmarks in FF did not transfer either?!

Answer (score 0):

Found the other ubuntu versions in drop-down menu on login page, default version has all files, folders & apps, great job, guys, but you sure know how to panic a user.